# How to add a button and overlap the circle image in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to overlap a `Button` with a `CircleImage` in `Xamarin.Forms` ?
I have created circle image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
  <Grid>
                    <ci:CircleImage 
            HeightRequest="120"   
            WidthRequest="120"   
            Source="profile.png"   
            Aspect="AspectFit">

        </ci:CircleImage>
                    <Button Text="Add Photo" CornerRadius="14" Margin="0,0,0,-10" Font="12" HeightRequest="35" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End"></Button> 
            </Grid>
```